# Link that will "preform" an SMS on android phone

Tags: android, sms, href, whatsapp, whatsapi

Im building a service that will send an invitation to an event through a WhatsApp group using whatsapp API.

Of course, it will require me to interact with the request to select the group and so on, which is OK, but there is no way (without expending money) for my app to "read" who will join.

I though in sending a link, which on tap, will generate an request on the guest to send me back an SMS, and then my app to "listen" and generate a database of those who agree to be in meeting (my app later will send another message to the group to confirm o cancel the meet according to the amount of people who get involved).

I think i can ask the people to send, but if i ask them to write the sms, they will not do it (lazy people).

There is a way i can write a link like "sms:myphonenumber?ImIn!" to send, so the device will build the SMS for them?

I know from a web u can do something like href:...., and will do the work for them, but not sure otherwise.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710188/how-to-open-sms-window-in-android-programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710188/how-to-open-sms-window-in-android-programatically)

Comment: Hi Alfro. This will not help. I cant run code on guest device... im looking something equivalent to sending a htttp link (this will open a browser on tap linking to a web page), but for preformatting a sms instead